# Best Practice for Server Processing

Tags: theme-development

In a theme I have a form that I need posted and some work done on the server. What is the recommended way of doing this?

I have it posting to another php file where some work will be done, and then redirected back to the previous url. I'm having some issues with this because all the functions that normally work in a page don't anymore; such as `home_url()` and `get_current_user_id()`. Is there a good/easy way to include the basic WP things to use?

Does the php file need to be a wordpress page? Is this even a good way doing this?

Comment: Is this for wp-admin or the front-end?

Comment: For the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at the AJAX in Plugins page which should solve your woes with redirects. http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

You can send whatever you want to be processed asynchronously. This is a pretty standard way of processing forms in WordPress both on the front-end and back-end.

If you need to include user data, add the current user ID to the jQuery.post data array to be sent to your AJAX hook.

Comment: I'd much rather do Ajax anyways. I wanted to whip up something quickly and found that things don't work the same on non templated files.

Comment: Yep. This keeps everything in the WP load sequence.